# Angular FormGroup returns AbstractControl instead of FormControl

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having a problem with my FormGroup in angular. On my page I have a form, which uses a FormGroup. This FormGroup is defined like this:

```
componentForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup<{
  logo: FormControl<string | null>,
  name: FormControl<string | null>,
  type: FormControl<ComponentTypeEnum | null>,
  configurable: FormControl<boolean | null>,
}>({
  logo: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  type: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  configurable: new FormControl(false, [Validators.required]),
});
```

Now I created foreach form input a separate component, so I am trying to pass each FormControl into the ChildComponent. This is how I defined one of the form input components:

```
export class FormTextInputComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() formElementName: string;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() defaultValue: string | undefined;
  @Input() control!: FormControl;

  inputValue: string | undefined;

  constructor() {
    this.formElementName = '';
    this.label = '';
    this.placeholder = '';
    this.inputValue = this.defaultValue ?? '';
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.inputValue = this.defaultValue ?? '';
  }
}
```

Then on the input inside that html I have:

```
<input
  type="text"
  [name]="formElementName"
  [value]="inputValue"
  [formControl]="control"
  class="input-field"
  placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
/>
```

However, when I am trying to pass the correct FormControl to the child element like this:

```
<app-form-text-input
  formControlName="name"
  [formElementName]="'name'"
  [label]="'Name'"
  [placeholder]="''"
  [defaultValue]="(component$ | async)?.name"
  [control]="componentForm.controls.name"
>
</app-form-text-input>
```

I get the error:

```
Type AbstractControl<any> is not assignable to type FormControl
```

Now why isn't this working. It looks like the `.controls` is for some reason an unknown type, because it doesn't have any special attributes other than:
[image]

Even when I try `['name']` it will give the same error. Personally I have always been a fan of passing the FormControl into the child component instead of using a ValueAccessor, so that's also not a way to go for me. Why doesn't my code recognise my FormControls inside the FormGroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `FormGroup` type annotation from `componentForm`, this way typescript will infer the type:

```
componentForm = new FormGroup<{
  logo: FormControl<string | null>,
  name: FormControl<string | null>,
  type: FormControl<ComponentTypeEnum | null>,
  configurable: FormControl<boolean | null>,
}>({
  logo: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  type: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  configurable: new FormControl(false, [Validators.required]),
});
```

Comment: I am still seeing this error in the console.log while everything is working:
`ERROR Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control name: 'name'. `... Any idea??

Comment: You're using the `FormControlName` directive on your `app-form-text-input`, which requires `FormTextInputComponent` to implement `ControlValueAccessor`. I think you can safely remove the directive, because you are passing the control into the component.